# multiple objects in flash (detecting object in event)

Tags: flash, events, flash-cs3

I want to create something like a scratch with 3 options. First website sends info about which field is correct. then flash replaces 2 movie clips with 'wrong' image and 1 with 'good' image. I already created scratch evect but in only works on 1 object. I don't know why?

I even tried duplication of event functions. Best way would be getting index of element. but how to pass it in event function?

Basically its just 3 black tiles with images on them. But why only the first object works?

My code is:

```
function getFlashVars():Object {
    return Object(LoaderInfo(this.loaderInfo).parameters);
}

var m = 0;

function stopRys(myszka:MouseEvent):void {
    m = myszka.currentTarget.tabIndex;
    cover[m].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, tworzMaske);
    image[m].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, tworzMaske);
}

function startRys(myszka:MouseEvent):void {
    m = myszka.currentTarget.tabIndex;
    cover[m].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, tworzMaske);
    image[m].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, tworzMaske);
}

function tworzMaske(myszka:MouseEvent):void {
    m = myszka.currentTarget.tabIndex;
    image[m].visible = true;
    rysuj[m].graphics.lineStyle(1);
    rysuj[m].graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    rysuj[m].graphics.drawCircle(mouseX, mouseY, 50);
    image[m].mask = rysuj[m];
}

var key1 = getFlashVars().key1;

var intWidth:Number = 200;
var intHeight:Number = 200;
var cover = new Array();
var image = new Array();
var rysuj = new Array();
var i:Number = 0;

for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    cover[i] = new MovieClip();
    image[i] = new MovieClip();
    rysuj[i] = new Sprite();

    cover[i]._x = intWidth*i;
    cover[i]._y = 0;
    cover[i].tabIndex = i;
    cover[i]._width = intWidth;
    cover[i]._height = intHeight;
    cover[i].graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    cover[i].graphics.drawRect(intWidth*i,0,intWidth,intHeight);
    cover[i].graphics.endFill();

    image[i]._x = intWidth*i;
    image[i]._y = 0;
    image[i].tabIndex = i;
    image[i]._width = intWidth;
    image[i]._height = intHeight;
    var myBitmapDataObject:przegrana = new przegrana(200, 200);
    var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapDataObject);
    image[i].addChild(myImage);

    addChild(cover[i]);
    addChild(image[i]);
    addChild(rysuj[i]);

    image[i].visible = false;

    image[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startRys);
    cover[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startRys);
    image[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopRys);
    image[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopRys);

}
```

**EDIT:**

Now i have some wierd problem. Events work only on first object just like it would be on whole flash movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "can't" pass custom arguments to even listeners. To know which object dispatched an event you can use myszka.target.

Comment: thanks, i try to pass it as tab index but still more problems :( more in topic